# Marcador personalizado no Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Como faço pra incorporar o mapa do Google mas com o marker personalizado?
Tem alguma API pública do Google Maps (que não requer key de acesso)?
Atualmente eu preciso incluir "toda" API, apenas para executar a operação de pegar (previamente) uma latitude, longitude e imagem do marker e marcar no mapa.

Java Script

Comment: É Javascript? Android? O que exatamente?

Comment: Ai que erro. É Java Script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para incluir o mapa, como você já deve estar fazendo e como indica na [documentação](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map), você de fato não precisa de nenhuma chave para isso. Logo, para customizar os marcadores também não é necessário uma chave, basta alterar os parâmetros deste marcador, incluindo a propriedade `icon`, como mostra **[aqui](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/custom-markers)**.

Por exemplo, uma vez que você tenha em seus arquivos uma imagem **novo_marcador.png**, basta ter algo assim:

```
var iconBase = 'http://www.seusite.com.br/icones/';

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  icon: iconBase + 'novo_marcador.png'
});
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, depois que li que não precisa chave, ficou mais simples. Inclusive criei uma mini API, onde passa (via atributos) a latitude, longitude, icone e escala, para então via API, calcular a altura (com escala), criar o mapa (incorpora a API Google também via API), setar a localização e o ícone. Assim, toda vez que eu precisar criar um mapa com o marcador, eu incorporo essa minha API e passo os parâmetros.